# Download a file from Dropbox with cURL

Tags: php, curl, download, dropbox

i would like to get some help about the following problem. I'm under windows and i'm able to download any files using the cURL, but when it comes to download from Dropbox i'm unable to do it. Even if i use ?raw=1 or ?dl=1 which is responsible to redirect me to the file i still can't do it.

Here is the script i'm using:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'any url?raw=1');

$fp = fopen('backup.wpress', 'w+');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Thanks in advance. I would be very grateful for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 302 redirect on that URL, so you'll need to add the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

(You also might want to edit that URL out the post, not sure if it's sensitive data...)